# C Segmentation Fault With Printf() and Scanf()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C, and I'm getting a segmentation fault that I can't understand. I have the following program, which attempts to calculates the number of factors of a strictly positive number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int numberOfFactors (int number, int factor) {
    if (number % factor == 0) {
        number = number/factor;
        return numberOfFactors(number, factor) + 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int check (int x) {
    if (x>0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int number;
    printf("Please enter a positive integer n such that n >= 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (check(number)){
        int i;
        for (i=1; i<=number; i++) {
            int factors;
            factors = numberOfFactors(number, i);
            printf("%d^%d ", i, factors);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The segmentation fault occurs immediately after entering an integer and ENTER after these lines in main():

```
printf("Please enter a positive integer n such that n >= 1: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
```

What in these lines is causing the segmentation fault, and what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: have you tried running under a debugger? It will likely stop at the exact line that's causing the fault.

Comment: No, I'm actually just typing this in TextWrangler and then FTPing it over to my schools Linux environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your recursion doesn't stop if you try to divide out factor one.

Just let factor never be 1:

```
    for (i=2; i<=number; i++) {
        int factors;
        factors = numberOfFactors(number, i);
        printf("%d^%d ", i, factors);
    }
```

---

I should say WHY it segfaults: It's because every function call pushes the current program counter (the position in your program where you currently stand) and function arguments on the stack (aka call stack), where the stack is a relatively small memory block used for, well, function calling and local variables.

So if you are pushing your stack too hard, it will fall over. End of game, aka segfault ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a problem with this recursion:

```
int numberOfFactors (int number, int factor) {
    if (number % factor == 0) {
        number = number/factor;
        return numberOfFactors(number, factor) + 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Change your numberOfFactors to something like:

```
int numberOfFactors (int number)
{
    int i=1;
    int ret=0;
    for(;i<=number;i++) {
        if (number%i == 0) {
            ret++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And then, change this portion:

```
if (check(number)){
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=number; i++) {
        int factors;
        factors = numberOfFactors(number, i);
        printf("%d^%d ", i, factors);
    }
}
```

To something simpler like:

```
if (check(number)){
    factors = numberOfFactors(number);
    printf("%d^%d ", number, factors);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it reaches there though because I threw some printf statements in there to check.

Comment: In fact I threw a printf immediately after the scanf in main and it never even made it that far.

Comment: @canton This can be very misleading. `stdout` is line buffered by default. So, it's possible for the program to crash with data still buffered. Your best bet is a debugger, but if you're going to use `printf()` make sure to end the string with `\n` or to `fflush(stdout);` immediately after

Comment: @canton: exactly as FatalError said on his/her comment.